# RAII - store `void*&` or `void**`

Tags: c++

I am working on design a wrapper class to provide RAII function.
The original use case is as follows:

```
void* tid(NULL);
OpenFunc(&tid);
CloseFunc(&tid);
```

After I introduce a new wrapper class, I expect the future usage will be as follows:

```
void* tid(NULL);
TTTA(tid);
```

or

```
TTTB(tid);
```

Question:

**Which implementation `TTTA` or `TTTB` is better? Or they are all bad and please introduce a better one.**

One thing I have concern is that after the resource is allocated, the `id` will be accessed outside of class `TTTA` or `TTTB` until the `id` is destroyed. Based on my understanding, my design should not have side-effect for that.

Thank you

```
class TTTA : boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    explicit TTTA(void *id)
        : m_id(id)
    {
        OpenFunc(&m_id); // third-party allocate resource API
    }

    ~TTTA()
    {
        CloseFunc(&m_id); // third-party release resource API
    }   
private:
    void* &m_id; // have to store the value in order to release in destructor
}

class TTTB : boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    explicit TTTB(void *id)
        : m_id(&id)
    {
        OpenFunc(m_id); // third-party allocate resource API
    }

    ~TTTB()
    {
        CloseFunc(m_id); // third-party release resource API
    }   
private:
    void** m_id; // have to store the value in order to release in destructor
}
```

// pass-in pointers comparison

```
class TTTD
{
public:
    TTTD(int* id)    // Take as reference, do not copy to stack.
        : m_id(&id)
    {
        *m_id = new int(40);
    }

private:
    int** m_id; 
};


class TTTC
{
public:
    TTTC(int* &id)    
        : m_id(id)
    {
        m_id = new int(30);
    }

private:
    int* &m_id; 
};

class TTTB
{
public:
    TTTB(int* id)    
        : m_id(id)
    {
        m_id = new int(20);
    }

private:
    int* &m_id; 
};

class TTTA
{
public:
    TTTA(int** id)    
        : m_id(id)
    {
        *m_id = new int(10);
    }

private:
    int** m_id; 
};


int main()
{
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int *pA(NULL);
    TTTA a(&pA);
    cout << *pA << endl; // 10

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int *pB(NULL);
    TTTB b(pB);
    //cout << *pB << endl; // wrong

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int *pC(NULL);
    TTTC c(pC);
    cout << *pC << endl; // 30

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int *pD(NULL);
    TTTD d(pD);
    cout << *pD << endl; // wrong
}
```

Comment: In C++, you generally use references to modify objects from within a function.

Comment: Based on my understanding, both `TTTA` and `TTTB` is equivalent.

Comment: No, the one uses a reference, the other uses a pointer.

Comment: Both `void**` and `void*&` can modify the pass-in `id` in the same way.

Comment: Not in the same way, but they can. References are not pointers.

Comment: Update: I forgot to add ': boost::noncopyable'.

Comment: What are the signatures of `OpenFunc` and `CloseFunc`?

Comment: @H2CO3: True that references are not pointers.  But when looking at how `TTTA` and `TTTB` act, the two classes are completely equivalent.

Comment: OpenFunc(void ***id); CloseFunc(void **id);

Comment: better to use references because it eliminates the need to check if the argument passed in is a valid void**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both break in bad ways.

TTTA stores a reference to a variable (the parameter id) that's stored on the stack.
TTTB stores a pointer to a variable that's stored on the stack.

Both times, the variable goes out of scope when the constructor returns.

EDIT: Since you want the values modifiable, the simplest fix is to take the pointer as a reference; that will make TTTC reference the actual pointer instead of the local copy made when taking the pointer as a non reference parameter;

```
class TTTC : boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    explicit TTTA(void *&id)    // Take as reference, do not copy to stack.
        : m_id(id)
...
private:
    void* &m_id; // have to store the value in order to release in destructor
}
```

The simple test that breaks your versions is to add a `print` method to the classes to print the pointer value and do;

```
int main() {

  void* a = (void*)0x200;
  void* b = (void*)0x300;

  {
    TTTA ta(a);
    TTTA tb(b);

    ta.print();
    tb.print();
  }
}
```

Both TTTA and TTTB print both values as 0x300 on my machine. Of course, the result is really UB; so your result may vary.

Comment: Your simple fix doesn't work for me. If you take `void* m_id` as the pass-in parameter, you are not able to modify the pass-in parameter. Also I expect the outside tid is void when the object of TTTA returns. For your example, I don't understand what the problem is since the print is called inside the scope and the result should be valid.

Comment: @q0987 See my edit for a modifiable version. The problem with TTTA/TTTB is that both take the pointer as a non reference parameter, that means it's copied to the stack in the constructor, a pointer/reference is taken to the location on the stack and when the constructor returns, the pointer/reference is left dangling. If you take the parameter as a reference, the passed in pointer is instead the one pointed to.

Comment: I have updated my OP and based on your comments, now I know my both `TTTA` and `TTTB` are wrong!

Comment: @q0987 If your question is still which is better, it's a matter of taste and what you find more readable. I prefer the reference syntax, since it avoids the "how many asterisks to dereference this pointer to pointer to something" puzzles that tend to slow me down.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you `tid` at all? It’s leaking information to the client and makes the usage twice as long (two lines instead of one):

```
class tttc {
    void* id;

public:

    tttc() {
        OpenFunc(&id);
    }

    ~tttc() {
        CloseFunc(&id);
    }

    tttc(tttc const&) = delete;
    tttc& operator =(tttc const&) = delete;
};
```

Note that this class forbids copying – your solutions break the rule of three.

If you require access to `id` from the outside, provide a conversion inside `tttc`:

```
void* get() const { return id; }
```

Or, if absolutely necessary, via an implicit conversion:

```
operator void*() const { return id; }
```

(But use that one judiciously since implicit conversions weaken the type system and may lead to hard to diagnose bugs.)

And then there’s [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) in the standard library which, with a custom deleter, actually achieves the same and additionally implements the rule of three properly.

Comment: b/c the `tid` is used in other functions and I don't wrapper those function inside the wrapper class.

Comment: Do you mean wrap the `tid` inside the TTT class and provide an accessor/getter function that returns the id? I am not sure this is a good idea. Since the other API may also modify tid.

Comment: @q0987 Yes. Like I said, see the updated answer. This **is** a good idea. So much so that it’s part of the standard library (again: `std::unique_ptr` does exactly that.)

Comment: The get function may not be marked as const since other function may modify it.

Comment: unique_ptr should be under tr1 in VS2010, e.g. `std::tr1::unique_ptr`

Answer (score 2):

What about wrapping it completely? This way you do not have to worry about managing the lifecycles of two variables, but only one.

```
class TTTC
{
    void* m_id;
public:
    TTTC()
        : m_id(nullptr)
    {
        OpenFunc(&m_id); // third-party allocate resource API
    }

    TTTC(TTTC const&) = delete; // or ensure copying does what you expect

    void*const& tid() const { return m_id; }

    ~TTTC()
    {
        CloseFunc(&m_id); // third-party release resource API
    }
};
```

Using it is simplicity itself:

```
TTTC wrapped;
DoSomethingWithTid(wrapped.tid());
```